# cross platform cli variable with a default value

Tags: node.js

in Linux we can do something like this `cmd --port=${PORT:-5000}` which uses `env.PORT` or the default value "5000"
but this doesn't work in Windows.

is there a cross-platform solution for it

Answer (score 1):

yes as you know in Linux, you can define a variable with the syntax `VARNAME=value`, while in Windows, you use the `set VARNAME=value` syntax.
actually there is a cross-platform solution for setting default values for CLI variables, in your case you can write something like this :

```
cmd --port=${PORT:=5000}
```

the command `cmd --port=${PORT:=5000}` sets the value of the 'port' variable to the value of the 'PORT' environment variable,fortunately, this syntax works in both Linux and Windows.

update
check this out:

```
const { exec } = require('child_process');

const port = process.env.PORT || '5000';
const cmd = `your-command-here --port=${port}`;
exec(cmd, (err, stdout, stderr) => {
  if (err) {
    console.error(err);
    return;
  }
  console.log(stdout);
});
```

as you see,my code uses the `process.env.PORT` to get the value of the `PORT` environment variable, it constructs the command with the appropriate port and runs it using `child_process.exec()`, and my code will work on both Linux and Windows!

Comment: this answer has two problems: 1- I tried `cmd --port=${PORT:=5000} && echo %port%` but the output is just "Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19045.3086]" instead of "5000"

2- I want to pass`--port=` as an argument of other commands like `http-server --port=${port:-5000}`

Comment: I tried `node app.js --port=${PORT:=5000}`, and in app.js I logged `console.log(process.env.port)` but it undefined

Comment: @Sheldeeb how about this ? `cmd /C "set PORT=5000 && your-command-here"`

Comment: this is window-specific only cmd, not a cross-platform solution